# How do you create a non persisted model with EmberData?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have an ember data app and I'm using `createRecord` to instantiate a model on a new records page. The problem is that this instantly creates the record in the store. So if someone navigates away from the the new record page the object is already persisted. There used to be a `createModel` method but it seems to have been removed. How is this handled now?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `Model.isNew` so you can see has it been persisted. For example, you can do following in Handlebars to display list of records from database and hide new non-persisted models when you, for example, navigate backwards from `model/add` route:

```
{{#each item in model}}
  {{#unless item.isNew}}
    {{item.name}}
  {{/unless}}
{{/each}}
```

According to [Ember API docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_createRecord), `DS.Store.createRecord` method:

> Creates a new record in the current store.

If you don't want to check if record `isNew`. You can have some properties for user input and call `createRecord` only if you are sure it can, and will, be persisted.

Comment: Hmm... So the answer is essentially that we need a mandatory filter?

Comment: I'm using this approach in my application and I didn't come across better solution.

Comment: It's not a bad suggestion, and I appreciate it. I'm hoping someone comes up with the proper 'ember' way but if not I'll accept yours.

Comment: If someone comes with better solution I'm also going to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, instead of checking for `Model.isNew` you can remove the record from the store once the user leaves the route using `Route.resetController` and `Store.unloadRecord`.

`Route.resetController` is meant for all controller clean up you have to do once the model changes or the user transitions away. IMHO this includes removing unsaved models from the store.

```
PostsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @store.createRecord 'post'

  resetController: (controller, isExiting, transition) ->
    @store.unloadRecord controller.get('model') if isExiting
```

See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_resetController and http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_unloadRecord